# Addressing multi-collinearity issues with subset selection methods

Tags: regression, self-study, multicollinearity

I'm a long-time lurker and first-time poster to this forum...

I am currently working my way through an Introduction to Statistical Learning, and I have a question regarding the algorithms presented for best and stepwise subset selection. Am I correct in assuming that none of these algorithms check for multi-collinearity between the predictor variables? Would the next step in the process be to look at the variables selected by these methods and then confirm that there is no multi-collinearity between the variables each method selects?  (I have experience in detecting multi-collinearity using the VIF factor)

I don't have a ton of experience in data science, but I have taken several graduate level business courses with an analytics focus, and I am having trouble understanding where one would use best and stepwise subset selection. Should these only be used when there are a lot of independent variables to explore and we are unsure what independent variables have a strong relationship with the dependent variable?

I am about to study the Lasso and Ridge regression sections of the book, and I think they may address the issue of multi-collinearity to where it isn't as much of a concern, but I wanted to make sure I was thinking about best and forward and backward stepwise selection the correct way.

Comment: A search of our site on [stepwise regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stepwise+regression) will give you helpful information.  (It is rather telling that the titles in the top hits begin "Why avoid" and "Main drawbacks of" ...)

Comment: @whuber I apologize for asking a question that's been asked 100 times already!  Please forgive me... I'll eventually ask some intelligent questions.  Why does one of the #1 recommended textbooks for statistical learning even discuss it?  It is it just to give context?

Comment: This site's users take an unusually dim view of stepwise regression, so bear that in mind.  It's a technique that has been in use for a couple of generations and IMHO when used judiciously can be effective--but it has been supplanted by superior techniques based on regularization and cross-validation that were either inaccessible or impossible to carry out on older computing platforms.  Since the largest, most popular university stats textbooks tend to stick around for 20-30 years past the dates they *should* be retired, don't be surprised to find this method discussed there.

Comment: BTW, your question is quite intelligent and meaningful.  But I do encourage you to do a little searching of our site whenever you are inspired to ask a new question, because it is our intention for such searches to be helpful.